# Scala: Which implicit parameter takes priority? The one declared where a method is defined? Or where the method is called?

Tags: scala, scope, sbt, implicit

If a method is defined in an object to take in an implicit parameter like this:

```
object MyApp {
   implicit val implicitParameter: String = "Hello!"

   def printImplicitString()(implicit ip: String): Unit = println(ip)
}
```

..and then this method is called in another object that that has its own implicit parameter of type `String`, which one gets precedence?

```
 object MyOtherApp extends App {

   implicit val implicitParamter2: String =  "World!"

   MyApp.printImplicitString()
 }
```

Does this print `Hello!` or `World!`? Can't get it to run in intellij, probably because it may be invalid code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one near the method call will take priority. Scala will start from the scope where the method is called and work its way backwards. According to Scala Docs [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html.html) and [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html):

> First, eligible are all identifiers x that can be accessed at the point of the method call without a prefix and that denote an implicit definition or an implicit parameter.
>
> Second, eligible are also all members of companion modules of the implicit parameter’s type that are labeled implicit

So this code will print 'World!'

Comment: "Will take priority" is a little misleading.  The implicit value in scope at the definition site is not even a candidate.

Comment: @JoePallas agreed. I used it as in "it will take priority over whatever else is in scope". A little bit ambiguous I agree but I don't think it is wise to lay the entire implicit scoping rules on someone who is trying to learn them. While the implicit near the definition is not a candidate it could have been in some other scenario (could have been mixed in with a trait or something). Really the bottom line is, one closest to the call always comes first